# Blender real-time animation based on the sensor data

Tags: python, armature, bones, blender-internal-render-engine

How can i animate the model in the image below based on sensor data? I need to make it real-time(like when person moves his arm, model in the blender should move too.) I tried keyframe_insert method for armatures but the animation it creates needs to be played. I need something simultaneous.

[image: Arm model]

Comment: Sounds as if Blender's old Game Engine would be more suitable for that. Try asking at https://upbge.org/

Comment: You can use the `modal` operator